# How can I make this a recursive statement in C#?

Tags: c#

The program needs to solve powers of 2 in a table showing n and 2n for n = 1 to 10. Here is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Power
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Number       Power of 2");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------");


            for (long counter = 1; counter <= 10; ++counter)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{counter, 2} {Power(counter), 20}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static long Power(long number, long exponentValue = 2)
        {
            long result = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                result *= exponentValue;
            }
                return result;

        }


    }
}
```

But it needs to be recursive. How can I make this function recursive?

Comment: While for Java (and another algorithm), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495744/converting-iteration-to-recursion) is quite similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: By calling itself until a condition is met. And you're not calculating a power, no? Edit: nevermind, just weird naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will look like this:

```
static long Power(long number, long exponentValue = 2)
{   
    if (number < 1)
    {
        return 0; // or throw exception because this shouldn't happen
    }

    if (number == 1)
    {
        return exponentValue;
    }

    return exponentValue * Power(number -  1, exponentValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RANT] 
*This one of those artificial problems meant to teach you about recursion, but doesn't do a good job because there are better non-recursive solutions (such as your current one). In fact, you usually want to convert a recursive solution TO a loop, to avoid possible stack-overflow errors!*
[/RANT]

In very general terms: To convert a loop to a recursive solution, you need to find a way of computing part of the solution, and then calling the method again to compute the remainder of the solution, until it is completely solved. There must also be a way to detect when no further recursion is needed.

In the case of computing a power, the answer will be:

```
Pow(X,N) => N * Pow(X,N-1)
```

And:

```
Pow(X,1) => X (this will be the state that terminates the recursion).
```

So think about how this works for X = 2 and N = 3:

```
Pow(2,3) => 2 * Pow(2,2)
Pow(2,2) => 2 * Pow(2,1)
Pow(2,1) => 2 (the terminating condition)
```

Here you wind up with 2*2*2 = 8, which is indeed 2^3.

Note how the N value goes down by 1 each time until it reaches 1, at which point no more recursion is required.

Writing this in C# terms:

```
static long Power(long number, long exponentValue)
{
    if (exponentValue == 1)
        return number;
    else
        return number * Power(number, exponentValue - 1);
}
```

Note: I did not write any error handling in order to focus on the recursive part. Real code would check that exponentValue was >= 1 and so on.

Further note: [The correct terminology for the power is "Exponent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) so I have used that terminology. You have it the wrong way around, so I would urge you to correct that! An exponent is the number of times the number is multiplied by itself.

Comment: Ah, well I'm going to stick with the correct naming. I'll update my answer to note that.

Comment: I think it's better to actually use **correct** naming and telling OP about it

Answer (score 0):

```
static long Power(long number, long exponentValue = 2)
{
    if (number == 1)
    { 
        return 1;
    }
    else
    { 
        return Power(number - 1, exponentValue) * exponentValue;
    }
}
```